# Generics типобезопасны?

Tags: java, generics, типизация

Если мы берем гомогенные джерики, т.е. которые используются в Java, являются ли они типобезопасными?

Если они все приводятся к одному общему типу при стирании, разве не должно быть так, что, например, в `List<String>` можно добавить Integer?

Comment: что ты понимаешь под "типобезопасностью"?

Comment: @Grundy Невозможность в рантайме получить ошибку неправильного приведения.

Comment: `Object ob = "some string"; int ob2 = (Integer)ob;`  отвалится в рантайме.

Comment: @tym32167 ну это никак не связано с дженериками.

Comment: @tym32167да и вопрос больше в том, как обеспечивается эта типибезопасность, потому что с гетерогенными дженериками все ясно, и мы все знаем их минусы, но вот про гомогенные я не обеспечен информацией.

Comment: ну ок, пример с генериками `public static <T> T fun(Object str){ return (T)str; }` отвалится при `int i = fun("strng");` в рантайме.

Comment: @kaylil_01, ну вообще все логично, раз генериков нет во время выполнения, то и ошибок приведения быть не может

Comment: @Grundy генериков нет, но приведение то есть во время выполнения.

Comment: @tym32167, тут нужно понять что имеет ввиду автор вопроса. Как понял я: можно добавить к коллекцию `List<String>` например integer - и это действительно можно сделать и ошибки не будет: https://onlinegdb.com/SybbnIx7D

Comment: @Grundy Ну я, наверное, дополню свою трактовку типобезопасности, невозможность использовать несовместимые вместе типы. Т.е. я не совсем понимаю, если после компиляции происходит стирание типов, почему я не могу добавить в лист стрингов - инт? Он до компиляции проверяет все?

Comment: @kaylil_01, а почему ты не можешь добавить в лист стрингов - инт? По ссылке есть пример - где вполне себе можешь.

Comment: @Grundy У меня локально не получается так сделать, но логически, это должно быть возможно.

Comment: @kaylil_01, что значит не получается?

Comment: @Grundy На байткоде - точно.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112180/discussion-between-grundy-and-kaylil-01).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Стирание происходит после компиляции, поэтому на уровне исходного кода добавить `Integer` в `List<String>` нельзя, компилятор не позволит. Можно на уровне байткода, но если вы занимаетесь грязными хаками в рантайме, то вы сам себе злой буратино. Обобщённые типы - это помощь программисту от случайных ошибок, а не защита от злонамеренных действий.

Comment: Ну в случае C++ такое не прокатить. Конечно, компилироваться будет так долго, что столько не живут, но все же.

Comment: @kaylil_01 что в С++ не прокатит?

Comment: @dIm0n в C++ нет стирания типов, поэтому всякие хаки в рантайме не прокатят.

Comment: @kaylil_01 https://stackoverflow.com/q/5450159/13970074

Comment: @dIm0n я имею в виду, что generics в с++ использует гетерогенную модель.